# "I was beside myself"

Tags: expressions

I have heard this phrase many times from people describing anguish, hysteria, or just plain being upset with some event in their lives. What is the correct definition and examples of it's use?

Comment: What research have you done to try to answer this yourself?

Comment: Why don't you consult an online dictionary?  Oald has a good explanation of "beside oneself".  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/beside?q=beside

Comment: Excuse me! Isn't this site about inquiries like this?

Comment: @J.K. This site is not for questions which can be answered by consulting a dictionary, grammar, thesaurus, or other standard reference. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of our purpose and standards.

Comment: +1. I totally disagree. Dictionary won't give in depth explanation why besides yourself is the way it is

Answer (score 4):

See [Today I Found Out: Feed your Brain](http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2015/01/origin-beside/)

> In 1476, William Caxton (1422-1492)......established the first English printing press at Westminster. Cornering the burgeoning book market, he
>   immediately began to print original English works (i.e., The
>   Canterbury Tales), as well as translations (often from French
>   editions). Notably, in 1490, he translated the Aeneid from a French
>   version, Eneydos.
>
> In the work, dedicated to King Henry VII’s son, Arthur, Caxton
>   translates the French phrase, “hors de soi” (meaning “outside
>   herself”) to “mad & **beside herself**” (with regard to Dido’s mental
>   state when she learned of Aeneas’ departure), marking the first time
>   the expression is used in print. (emphasis added)

Another source, [The Free Dictionary by Farlex](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beside+onesel) says:

***beside oneself***

> In a state of extreme agitation or excitement, as in She was beside
>   herself when she found she'd lost her ring, or Peter was beside
>   himself with joy-he'd won the poetry award. This phrase appears in the
>   New Testament (Acts 26:24): "Paul, thou art beside thyself; much
>   learning makes thee mad." (late 1400s)

Comment: Thank you "ab2" for the explanation of "Beside Yourself". I didn't realize how well this phrase has been documented over time. It shed's a new light on what I had interpreted. You, unlike others that have responded to my question, does show that you have a lot of class and considerate of others that do not have the knowledge or the resources to do research. Rude and snarky comments from other members will eventually inhibit future growth of this website. Not a good way to embark on a learning expedition for sure. Thank you again "ab2"

Comment: @J.K. Thank you for the compliment.  Learning how to research your questions takes time.  A surprising amount comes up on a simple google search.

Answer (score 2):

More interesting even than a plain definition is the reason for such a phrase…

The phrase ***to be beside oneself*** stems from the idea that one is oneself only when in control, when one's emotional balance is not upset.

Think of its antonyms, ***enraptured***, ***rapt***, when you are stolen away from yourself because of intense pleasure or concentration, when you acknowledge also that the states of bliss or extreme focus you are in are not natural.

The upsetting of one's emotional balance can originate in an excess of grief or joy: in both cases, the events fill one with feelings that appear to be some kinds of divine or ungodly visitations; nothing, that is, that one should be held accountable for… a very easy way – still very much in favour today in our irreligious age – for human beings of exonerating themselves!

Comment: Interesting definitions! Thank you "user58319"